# Implementing a copy method of a class implementing an interface - Java

Tags: java, interface, shallow-copy

I have this weird situation, where I have a class TheClass implementing interface TheInterface and class TheClass is supposed to have a copy() method with return type TheInterface, and it should make a shallow copy of itself. When trying to call my function copy() and use it, I get an Incompatible types error. I need to keep the return type of the copy() method as it is.

Is there some way how to do this?

Thank you

```
class TheClass implements TheInterface,Cloneable {


private Set<Integer> set;

public TheClass(){
    set=new HashSet<Integer>();
}

public TheInterface copy() {
    TheInterface clone = this.clone();
    return clone;
}

protected A clone(){
    A clone;
    try
    {
        clone = (A) super.clone();
    }
    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
    {
        throw new Error();
    }
    return clone;
}
```

here i get the incompatible types error

```
public class Main  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TheClass class1 = new TheClass();
    TheClass class2 = class1.copy();
```

Comment: `TheClass` is not the same type as `TheInterface`

Comment: Other classes can in theory implement that interface.  You can't take any random implementation and assign it as a `TheClass` without casting.

Comment: Your `copy` method shouldn't be calling `this.copy()`. That's an infinite recursion.

Comment: I understand, but I cannot think of any other way how to implement this copy() method. The return type has to be TheInterface. Do you have an idea?

Comment: there was meant to be this.clone() . this mistake was not in the code itself

Comment: @petex7 TheClass implements TheInterface - as such you can return TheClass as TheInterface.

Comment: @Worthless that dont work for me for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial improvement might be to make `copy()` in `TheClass` return `TheClass`, while the method in interface still returns `TheInterface`. This is allowed since return type is not part of Java's method signature.

This way, you could do

```
TheClass class1 = new TheClass();
TheClass class2 = class1.copy();
```

However, if you call `copy()` on a variable of (static) type `TheInterface`, you still have to assign it to `TheInterface` (but that seems logical):

```
TheInterface class1 = new TheClass();
TheInterface class2 = class1.copy(); // cannot be TheClass in this case
```

Comment: With generics you could also defined the copy method so that any TheInterface implementation can be assigned, eg

    public <T extends TheInterface> T copy() { .. }